# Grohe Lacuna kitchen faucet aerator doesn't works properly

Tags: kitchen-sink

I bought the faucet about 1 year and half ago. comparing with the other brands and the grohe's other models, this one's aerator has not shown me properly functioning ever: it alway seems to be high water pressure - put my hand or any objects in the water stream out of the spray, water will be splush to every where in my sink and the counter, no matter how I adjust the incoming water flow, and it happens with its two spray modes.

I have contacted grohe cstomer service, and they sent me replacement of the aerator assembly, with the new parts, it behaves the same.

I have been thinking that this is a problem with the screens with in the aerator, or I missed some parts other than the aeretor?

Any comments are appreciated.

Thanks,
Heinz

Comment: are you saying that the water comes out with high force even when the water is turned on very low?

Comment: Yes. the aerator does not seem to be doing what it should do

Comment: the aerator introduces air into the water stream ... it does not do anything else

Comment: I knew that. the water stream from the faucet should be smoothy and quiet, and "soft" and no water splush when you touch it with hands, that's what missing. no air or not enough air introduced into?